# Cannot overwrite out dir using declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm using `Typescript` and in `tsconfig.json` I'm getting this error:

> Cannot write file 'c:/michael/Documents/razor/lib/client.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.

this is my `tsconfig.json` content:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./lib",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "test"
    ]
}
```

as you can see I have enabled `declaration: true` to export also the `d.ts` files.
This is my project folders structure:

```
/lib
/node_modules
/src
/test
.gitignore
.npmignore
razor-1.0.0.tgz
package.json
packages-lock.json
readme.md
tsconfig.json
```

If I try to run `tsc -p` I cannot compile, so each time I must delete the folder `lib` manually which contains the compiled project.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is picking up files from `lib` directory when compiling. Hence, that error. Try adding `lib` to the `exclude` array.

Comment: yep, it's right.. thanks! I have to restart vs code though